# Question on cone of projective algebraic set $V$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have a projective algebraic set $V \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ and its cone $C(V) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$. I was wondering about the following statement: $V$ is irreducible if and only if $C(V)$ is irreducible.

I am guessing it is true.
I can show that $C(V)$ is irreducible implies $V$ is irreducible, but I was having trouble showing the other direction. I would appreciate any hints/proof! Thank you!

Comment: They have the same ideal, and the question is whether that ideal is prime, no?

Comment: Yes. I guess so! Thank you!